# Don't understand what "ping "website" > list" is

Tags: cmd, io-redirection

Had an exam where i had this question but could not find an awnser to it.
The exact words translated: "what does the command "ping [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) > list" do in cmd" after 1 hour of googleing i found nothing about the "> list" part.

All info i found was about ping and list's but nothing about the affix "list" if there is any.

I am also somewhat unsure as to what i am looking for so anything could be usefull.

Comment: Please read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) or [Command Redirection, Pipes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) from [SS64.com - A-Z index of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/). I don't understand why Microsoft has no page on [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) explaining the general syntax of Windows command processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>` operator is a redirection of the output of the command on the left to the file on the right. The basic syntax is:

```
command > file
```

This means that in your example `ping www.example.com > list` a ping command is done on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and instead of writing the output of the ping command to the command window it writes the output to the file named "list".

The ping command output looks like this:

```
C:\>ping www.example.com

Pinging www.example.com [93.184.216.34] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 93.184.216.34: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=56
Reply from 93.184.216.34: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=56
Reply from 93.184.216.34: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=56
Reply from 93.184.216.34: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 93.184.216.34:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 93ms, Maximum = 93ms, Average = 93ms
```

With your example it is not displayed on screen but written to the file "list". I suggest to use a proper file name extension for the target file name, e.g. "list.txt".